# Groovy Script to read particular value

Tags: json, groovy

I am able to fetch the value from a particular JSON payload via the below script. If there are multiple 'id' fields then I want to extract the value starting with "asset:" . Please help me.

Suppose , the following fields coming and I want to fetch the value starting with "asset:" (random orders)

```
"id":"Batch:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc",
"id":"assetTypeID:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc",
"id":"assetType:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc",
"id":"asset:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc",
```

**Existing Code:** (using to fetch first id value)

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def Message processData(Message message)
 {
        def body = message.getBody(String);
        def map = new JsonSlurper();
        def object = map.parseText(body)
        def id =  object.data.id[0].toString()
        message.setHeader("id",id )
        return message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def data = [ "id":"Batch:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc", "id":"assetTypeID:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc", "id":"assetType:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc", "id":"asset:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc", ]

def id = data.findResult{ k, v -> v.startsWith( 'asset:' ) ? v : null }

assert id == 'asset:6166a7e352faff0007dfa7dc'
```

Comment: Could you please help me achieving the same by editing the following code

Comment: {
        def body = message.getBody(String);
        def map = new JsonSlurper();
        def object = map.parseText(body)
        def id =  object.data.id[0].toString()
        message.setHeader("id",id )
        return message
}

Comment: please post your code into the original question. It's close to impossible to read it from the comment...

Comment: I have already posted the existing the Groovy code.

Comment: I need a valid sample of `message.getBody(String)`